# Is $g(x) = \int_1^x \sqrt{f(y)}e^{-\int_1^yf(z)dz}dy$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:D = [1,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be bounded and Lebesgue measurable.
I am checking if the function
\begin{equation*}
g(x) = \int_1^x \sqrt{f(y)}e^{-\int_1^yf(z)dz}dy
\end{equation*}
is bounded or not.
What I have tried is to divide $D$ into $I_1 = \{x:f(x)\ge1\}$, $I_2 = \{x:f(x)\le 1/x^4\}$, and $I_3 = \{x:1/x^4<f(x)<1\}$ and check the integral in each case.
Then, I could check 
\begin{equation*}
\int_{I_i} \sqrt{f(y)}e^{-\int_1^yf(z)dz}dy \le 1
\end{equation*}
for $i\in\{1,2\}$.
But, I cannot prove or disprove the boundedness for $i = 3$.
Would you give me any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = \frac1{x^2}, x\geq 1$, the function $g$ is not bounded.